# Short story with competitors complaining to government about a new very popular synthetic food

Tags: story-identification

Synthetic foods are all the rage, and while some are new and novel, many are attempts to recreate the taste and texture of a natural foods, with varying degrees of success. One company introduces a new synthetic food that becomes wildly popular. The competition analyzes it, and based on discovering what natural creature it is based on, they petition the government to ban it.

> They discover that the product is synthetic human flesh, so consuming it is not technically cannibalism, but it is similar, as they explain to the panel of government officials.

Comment: STACK EXCHANGE IS PEOPLE!!!  [Hufu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hufu) was a very similar idea.  It turned out to be a joke, but it was very convincing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's Arthur Clarke's '[Food of the Gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Food_of_the_Gods_%28short_story%29).'

Most of the story is giving backstory to the development of the product line, and how, revolting as the idea is to them now, humans used to eat animal flesh.

> "You and I, gentlemen, come from a long line of carnivores. I see from your expressions that most of you don't recognize the term."

The current popular food is basically a replication of meat, and the new, massively popular food line ("Ambrosia Plus") is.. well, the narrator prepares to explain it's origin...

> "When I began my evidence, I used the archaic word "carnivore". Now I must introduce you another: I'll spell it out the first time: C-A-N-N-I-B-A-L... "