# 50s/60s short story in which a tourist on Mars becomes dinner

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

In this short story probably from the 50s or 60s, a tourist on Mars meets a beautiful woman who invites him for dinner with her family. The problem is that with a meat shortage on Mars, he becomes the dinner!

Comment: Except for the setting being Mars, this could fit with the plot for the film, *Delicatessen" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delicatessen_(film))

Answer (score -1):

So the only thing about Mars and cannibalism that comes to mind from the 50/60s is the short story ["The Food of the Gods"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Food_of_the_Gods_%28short_story%29) (1964) Arthur C. Clarke,. But it takes place in Congress and starts with a lengthy description of the curious repeated success of a food processing company.

Comment: What short story by Asimov?  For a proper story ID answer, you need to, ahem, ID the story.

Comment: It sounds like you are thinking of [Food of the Gods](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77097/short-story-with-competitors-complaining-to-government-about-a-new-very-popular/77098#77098), which is actually by Clarke.

Comment: Yes yes yes, Clarke, my bad.

Comment: I've edited in what you actually think the answer is, according to the comments here, if you are answering a story id question you should include the work that you think it is in the answer else the information you have is better served as a comment on the question.