# A short story that ends with a character spelling C.A.N.N.I... (BAL implied)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A long time ago I read a short Sci-Fi story and I'm trying to figure out its Title/Author. Here is the plot and the last line:

An attorney for one food producing company is trying to get the product of another company banned. He is standing up in front of a bunch of government officials or legislatures. All food is processed food in their economy; none of it is from animals. Indeed most people don't even know about meat. So the attorney has to explain what food used to be. At one point he introduces a word by spelling it out... C.A.R.N.I.V.O.R.E.... and one member of the audience gets ill (he had warned them it would be a difficult topic) and has to leave.
After explaining all about meat, and different kinds of meat, and that their competitor has designed several of their foods to taste like meat,a  he says, and this is a pretty much quote, I think, "So now I have to explain about another word: C.A.N.N.I..." [end of story]

Comment: Welcome to SciFi Stack Exchange.  You've asked one of the more popular / common questions.  I've answered it below, but it is a duplicate; once you confirm the answer (thus confirming it to be a dup), we'll close it as a dup, and link it to one of the other answers (such as [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/77097/short-story-with-competitors-complaining-to-government-about-a-new-very-popular/77098#77098))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That story sticks in a lot of people's minds; you are looking for Arthur Clarke's '[Food of the Gods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Food_of_the_Gods_%28short_story%29).'

Most of the story is giving backstory to the development of the product line, and how, revolting as the idea is to them now, humans used to eat animal flesh.

> "You and I, gentlemen, come from a long line of carnivores. I see from your expressions that most of you don't recognize the term."

The current popular food is basically a replication of meat, and the new, massively popular food line ("Ambrosia Plus") is.. well, the narrator prepares to explain it's origin...

> "When I began my evidence, I used the archaic word "carnivore". Now I must introduce you another: I'll spell it out the first time: C-A-N-N-I-B-A-L... "